# How to compare maps and store the result into Value Objects using Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to process 3 hashmaps and place their data into a List of value objects.  However, I'm having a problem with my code failing somewhere.

Here is the scenario for what I'm trying to accomplish:

Map1 is the source map , map2 and map3 are used to compare against map1.  Finally I store the result into a VO (Value Object).

```
    HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal> map1=new HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>();

    map1.put(1,10)
    map1.put(2,20)
    map1.put(3,30)
    map1.put(4,40)
    map1.put(5,50)

    Map<Integer,String> map2=new HashMap<Integer,String>();


    map2.put(1,"Y");
    map2.put(2,"N");

   Map<Integer,String> map3=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

   map3.put(3,"N");
   map3.put(4,"N");
   map3.put(5,"N");


public Map<Integer, BigDecimal> process(
            final Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map1,
            final Map<Integer, String> map, final List<EmployeeVO> empDetails) {

        final Iterator<Integer> keys = map1.keySet().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            final EmployeeVO empVO = new EmployeeVO();
            final Integer empKeys = keys.next();
            empVO.setEmpId(empKeys);
            empVO.setEmpAmount(map1.get(empKeys));

            if (("Y".equals(map.get(empKeys)))) {

                empVO.setInd("Y");
                keys.remove();

            } else
                empVO.setInd("N");
            empDetails.add(empVO);
        }

        return map1;
    }
```

EmployeeVO:

```
    public class EmployeeVO{

    private BigDecimal empAmount=new BigDecimal(0);
    private Integer empId;
    private String ind;

   //setters and getters

   }
```

I am calling above method like below,surprisingly i am getting 10 records into my list object.Can you please tell me me how to fix this.

```
    final List<EmployeeVO> empDetails = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EmployeeVO>();

    final Map<Integer, BigDecimal> result1 = process(map1, map2, empDetails );
   final Map<Integer, BigDecimal> result2 = process(map1, map3, empDetails );
```

Expected Result : list should contain 5 VO objects,But is is having 9 records

Comment: We understand that your code is failing somewhere, but we can't see your code. Post it/

Comment: You need to post the code so we can help you!

Comment: sorry for this,posted code

Comment: Start a debugger, breakpoint on `empDetails.add()`, work your way backwards to see why the method gets called way too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is here:

```
if (("Y".equals(map.get(empKeys))))
```

Because your map is a raw map, not of generic type (it's value is not a String). You've defined this map as:

```
HashMap map2=new HashMap();
HashMap map3=new HashMap();
```

Try making it:

```
Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

You need to make `empDetails` also a map:

```
final Map<Integer, EmployeeVO> empDetails = new HashMap<Integer, EmployeeVO>();
```

And have `process` method as:

```
void process(final Map<Integer, Integer> map1,
        final Map<Integer, String> map, final Map<Integer, EmployeeVO> empDetails) {

    final Iterator<Integer> keys = map1.keySet().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        EmployeeVO empVO = new EmployeeVO();
        Integer empId = keys.next();
        empVOsetEmpId(empId);
        empVO.setEmpAmount(map1.get(empId));

        if (("Y".equals(map.get(empId))))
            empVO setInd("Y");
        else
            empVO setInd("N");
        empDetails.put(empId, empVO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright then please edit your question with updated code so that I can investigate.

Comment: It is giving exact same result no change

Comment: I understand that but unless I see your latest code I won't be able to investigate it.

Comment: Inside `process` method you still have `final Map<?, ?> map`. That should be changed to: `final Map<Integer, String> map`

Comment: After first call to `process`: `empDetails` will contain 5 elements. After second call to `process`: `empDetails` will contain 9 elements. If you see code inside `process` it is obvious also since 1st element from map1 gets removed because `map2.get(1).equals("Y")` is true.

Comment: that is correct ,i want all 5 records from map 1 and "Y" or "N" from map2 and map3.

Comment: empid from  map1 key,empAmount from map1 value.Y or N from map2,map3 based on map1 key,map2 key,map3 key

Comment: But that is not happening in your code inside `process`. And why is `.remove()` being called. I think you need to build your understanding of coding in Java first. Use some IDE to right the code (you will avoid making some basic mistakes). I need to leave now since it is pretty late at night here.

Comment: anubhava ,Problem is my final arraylist contains 9 objects. How to ensure only it has 5 objects with ind values along with other data.

Comment: Ok check the edited code now. I suggest once again you to please devote some time learning about programming in Java.

Comment: anubhava, thanks.i know this approach.But here there is posiibility of  hash collission.if same keys are replaced twice.suppose  take in fist time proceess key 1 has N but in second time of procees method invocation jey 1 has Y.so here replacing 1 key with new EmpVo object.

Comment: You can call `if (empDetails.containsKey(empId)( {...}` to make sure that empId is not already there and skip the insertion in that case.

Comment: No,But i want that updated recrod.Any way thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Even if you want that particular value to be updated, you can just update a single field rather than overwriting whole object. With `empDetails` as a map things become easy to manage.

Comment: Actually `HashMap` will be faster than `CopyOnWriteArrayList` any day. You can run the benchmarks yourself.

Comment: unfortunately i have to use ConcurrentHashMap .if i override hashcode and equals is my problem solve?

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable inputs